# Count cases using segmentation variable in SPSS

Tags: statistics, spss

I have an SPSS dataset with more than 5,000 cases that looks like this:

```
ID, relation to head of household
1, head of household
1, son
1, partner
2, head of household
2, son
3, head of household
3, son
3, cousin
```

I need to count the number of households that have

1. Head of household + child(s)
2. Head of household + partner + child(s)
3. Head of household + relative(s)
4. Head of household + partner + relative(s).

I know this should be done using ID as segmentation variable, but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to make a set of dummy variables for each category and then use AGGREGATE to get the household level statistics.

```
DATA LIST LIST (",") /ID (F1.0) Relation (A20).
BEGIN DATA
1,head of household
1,son
1,partner
2,head of household
2,son
3,head of household
3,son
3,cousin
END DATA.
DATASET NAME Houses.

*Making dummy variables.
COMPUTE HeadHouse = (Relation = "head of household").
COMPUTE Partner = (Relation = "partner").
COMPUTE Child = (Relation = "son").
COMPUTE Relative = (Relation = "cousin").

DATASET DECLARE AggHouse.
AGGREGATE OUTFILE='AggHouse'
  /BREAK ID
  /HeadHouse = SUM(HeadHouse)
  /Partner = SUM(Partner)
  /Child = SUM(Child)
  /Relative = SUM(Relative).
```

Then with the aggregated dataset you can subsequently use IF statements to calculate the conditions you want. E.g.

```
DATASET ACTIVATE AggHouse.
IF (HeadHouse > 0) AND (Child > 0) First = 1.
IF (HeadHouse > 0) AND (Partner > 0) AND (Child > 0) Second = 1.
```

For your real dataset you will need to insert more conditions for both the original set of dummy variables, but I leave that as an exercise to you.